# Arbitrary $2\times 2$ unitary matrix using waveplates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, unitarity

I'm studying about the quantum computation using quantum optics and I wonder about how to implement arbitrary $2\times 2$ unitary operation using waveplates such as half wave plates and quarter wave plates.

Is it possible to implement arbitrary $2\times 2$ single qubit unitary operation using waveplates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short-answer:** yes, it is! The whole business about using light's degrees of freedom for encoding information on qubits relies on using stuff like half and quarter-wave plates for changing polarization, or mode converters for working with transverse modes.

**A bit longer-answer**: A general SU(2) operation can be represented by three independent real parameters on the hypersphere $S^3$, and there are different types of parametrization. For example, it can be characterized as a rotation by an angle $\psi \in [0, \pi]$ around a unit vector $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ oriented along the direction given by the sagittal $(\theta \in [0, \pi])$ and azimuthal $(\phi \in [0, 2\pi])$ angles, which gives
\begin{eqnarray}
U &=& R_{\mathbf{\hat{n}}}(\psi) = e^{-i\,\psi\,\mathbf{\hat{n}}\,\cdot\,\pmb{\sigma}}
=\cos\psi\,I - i\sin\psi\, \mathbf{\hat{n}}\cdot\pmb{\sigma}\;,
\nonumber\\
u &=& \cos\psi - i\cos\theta\sin\psi\;,
\nonumber\\
w &=& -i\sin\theta\sin\psi \,e^{i\phi}\;.
\label{eq:UR}
\end{eqnarray}

Another possible parametrization uses the Euler angles, which are suitable for optical implementations with polarization components. In this parametrization, a general SU(2) matrix can be written as a sequence of three rotations characterized by the Euler angles $(\varphi, \xi, \zeta)$
%
\begin{eqnarray}
&&    U(\varphi,\xi,\zeta) = R_y(\varphi)\, R_z(-\xi)\, R_y(\zeta)\;,
    \nonumber\\
&&    u = \cos\xi\cos(\varphi+\zeta) + i \sin\xi\cos(\varphi-\zeta)\;,
    \nonumber\\
&&    w = \cos\xi\sin(\varphi+\zeta) + i \sin\xi\sin(\varphi-\zeta)\;.
\label{SU2Euler}
\end{eqnarray}

It provides a simple relationship between the group parameters and the orientations of retardation devices, such as half- and quarter-wave plates used for polarization transformations, or mode converters used for transverse mode operations.

According to the J[ones matrix representation](https://opg.optica.org/josa/abstract.cfm?uri=josa-31-7-488), the most general SU(2) operator can be decomposed as a product of waveplate operations in the following way:

\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq:QWP+HWP+QWP-Matrix}
   U &=& \text{QWP}(\eta_1) \, \text{HWP}(\tau)\, \text{QWP}(\eta_2)\;,
\end{eqnarray}

where

\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq:QWP+HWP+QWP-Matrix2}
\text{QWP}(\eta) &=& R_y(\eta)\,Q_0\,R_y(-\eta)\;,
\nonumber\\
\text{HWP}(\tau) &=& R_y(\tau)\,H_0\,R_y(-\tau)\;,
\nonumber\\
Q_0 &=&\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \,\,\,0\\
0 & \,\,\,i\\
\end{array}
\right)\;,
\nonumber \\ 
H_0 &=& \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \,\,\,0\\
0 & -1\\
\end{array}
\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

For a complete description and example take a look at this paper: [Spin-orbit implementation of the Solovay-Kitaev decomposition of single-qubit channels](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02631)